# how to calculate this lambda calculus? is there order of calculation is important?

Tags: lambda

I try to calculate this lambda expression but I don't have a assurance.

(λy.x z) (λx.(a b c) λy.(y x) (λx.x y)) b

```
when i try from head, 
x (λx.(a b c) λy.(y x) (λx.x y)) b
x ((a b c) x y ) b
```

And i want to know about reduction order is affect the result.

Is this correct? and I don't know next step because of above expression don't have 'λ(argument).' statement.
Then what is the next step calculation?

Comment: Can you break this down into individual steps?

Comment: (λy.x z) to x λx.(a b c)  λy.(y x) to x (λx.x y) to y so x ( λx.(a b c) x y ) b